# Why is line breaking output with STEP different in pdfTeX vs. XeTeX/LuaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, line-breaking

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}\usepackage[]{step}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This gives different placement depending on engine, for some reason I cannot figure out (it's using the same Type 1 fonts no matter what). The different engines don't seem to want to break in the same place, and as a result, there is a one-line difference between the pages (the last line ending in "port-" is pushed to the next page in Lua/Xe). This doesn't seem to occur with other fonts (I tried with `times` and `stix` and got the same breaks across engines). What gives?

Page 1 with pdfLaTeX (same in DVI and PDF mode):
[image: Page 1 with pdfLaTeX (same in DVI and PDF mode)]

Page 1 with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX:

[image: Page 1 with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While luatex is known to be potentially incompatible with pdftex in terms of line breaking, this is actually not the case here. (Also, AFAIK `xetex` is supposed to yield the same line breaks.)

Rather, the difference lies in the value of `\parindent`. This gets fixed when the document class is loaded, when it is set to 1.5em (in `size12.clo`). Now, 1em translates to different lengths in pdftex on the one hand, and xetex/luatex on the other, because of the different default fonts: OT1/cmr, where 1.5em=17.62482pt, and TU/lmr, where 1.5em=18pt.

This small difference is enough for the first line of the third paragraph to be hyphenated differently.

The fix is to reset `\parindent` after the new default font is defined (ie. after `\usepackage{step}`):

```
\normalfont
\parindent=1.5em
```

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation on LuaTeX line breaking changes?

Comment: @d909 See the luatex manual, section 5.7 (Breaking paragraphs into lines) and the sections leading up to it.